# How to use selenium IDE in python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

I'm trying to record actions in browser by using python.
Is it possible to use selenium IDE from python or is there other way to realize it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html ?

Comment: Selenium is used for automating things not recording user interactions with the browser.